# How do you select the best time series model?

Tags: time-series

If you are given the parameter estimates and their p value and ACF PACF only how to can you chose the most suitable model if there are more than one model where parameters are significant?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would need at least the log-likelihood value of the model output or an information criterion.

Just with the parameter estimates, their p-value and the ACF/PACF is not a good model selection. Remeber, that the parameter estimates depend on each other, therefore selection on nonsignifianct p-values is not a good idea.

Since you said, that you have more models, in which (all?) parameters are significant, I guess that all p-values are very small so the difference between the p-values of the models is negligible.

Do you have the ACF/PACF of the observations or of the residuals?

If you have the ACF/PACF of the observations you can use them to identify significant spikes in the plots and from this, identify the appropriate ARMA(p,q).

If you have the ACF/PACF of the residuals there should be no significant spikes, also, up to a certain lag order the autocorrelation coefficients should be jointly equal to zero. So if at the first lag orders some spikes are almost significant, you can say, that jointly the autocorrelation coefficients will be different to zero and therefore the model fit is not appropriate (the residuals should behave white noise).

If you have the ACF/PACF of the squared residuals you can check for ARCH effects and say, that the models which takes this into account is the best model.

If you have the ACF/PACF of the squared standardized residuals you can check if your model for the volatility equation could remove any ARCH effects and therefore if it is appropriate.